# Minecraft /clear help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I would like to clear ANY item with a lore of "This is an item of death.." I can achieve this with a diamond chest plate by doing `clear @a minecraft:diamond_chestplate -1 -1 {display:{Lore:[This is an item of death..]}}`

But I want to be able to do this with one command block and no scoreboards. In other words I need to know how to specify any item.

Comment: As far as I am aware, you cannot do this with one command.

Comment: As far as I know, the lore for clear can be done from command blocks. There is no actual way to _specify_ an item. You just need to give it something unique (like an enchantment, name, lore, etc.).

Comment: @JohnSmith What do you mean by "no actual way to specify an item"? There are ids... to specify the type of item (e.g. diamond_chestplate). Of course, the exact item object (in the game code) cannot be accessed through a cmd-block.

Comment: @1Darco1 yes with ids. But i mean like this one unique item. That cannbe distinguished from same id items through effects, name, lore

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I specify only NBT in the /clear command, not an item?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/373037/how-can-i-specify-only-nbt-in-the-clear-command-not-an-item) or [How to remove specific NBT items from player inventory without data packs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/381367/185203) (closing older question as duplicate of newer question because this question has an outdated answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is technically impossible to be done with a single command block. If you want to enter metadata (like `{display:{Lore:[This is an item of death..]}}`) you have to enter the item type in the other argument in order to work, that means you have to specify the item type.

Comment: Could you suggest a way to do this with more then one command block?

Comment: You would do "clear @a <item_type> <data> 64 {display:{Lore:[This is an item of death..]}}" replacing <item_type> with each of the items that you would clear, and <data> with the durability of that item to clear (used in colored wool and others).