# Clear every Item with Custom Lore or CustomModelData

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am looking a solution to clear all items of any type but with a `CustomModelData` or `Lore` tag out of the players inventory.

Example: I have a stick in my inventory with the `CustomModelData` or Lore test and a hoe also with the `CustomModelData` or `Lore` test, with the following commands:

```
/clear @p stick{CustomModelData:<...>,display:{Lore:['{"text":"MyLore"}']}}
```

But how can I make it work with *any* item with the NBT, not just the stick and hoe?

Comment: I've actually asked this question before, and received a very good answer to it. Check it out: [How can I specify only NBT in the /clear command, not an item?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/373037/250180)